# Where is the disk.db in sails?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Where is the disk.db in sails.js? I don't see it in the .tmp folder. I added a user model and controller and was able to add a user and query. I also stopped and restarted the app so it must be stored somewhere.

Comment: You're right. I see it in the .tmp directory now and it's called "localDiskDb.db"

Answer (score 18):

By default, it's in .tmp/

It can be placed somewhere else, though, if you change the config:

```
localDiskDb: {
  adapter: 'sails-disk',
  filePath: '/data/'
},
```

And it goes to /data instead of .tmp/

Comment: just wanted to say thanks for this - although I was getting permission errors with the preceding slash on the filepath for some reason - this worked for me: 
`localDiskDb: {
  adapter: 'sails-disk',
  filePath: 'data/'
},`

Answer (score 10):

Unless you're using an adapter other than `sails-disk`, it's in `.tmp/`.